# How can I save a custom level in Daisy’s Garden 2 in a DGF file?

Tags: gaming, editor

I have the game "Daisy’s Garden 2" running in DOSBox with Windows 3.1.

If I now create a custom garden level, how can I save it as a DGF file? When I click "Save as", nothing happens.

While testing the level, how do I return to the edit view?

Comment: Can't see much of a reason why this question should be closed. It's totally on-topic.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Windows 3 game from 1997. The DOSBox reference is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

I have installed the shareware version of Daisy's Garden 2 within Windows NT 4 under VirtualBox. In this environment the game runs too slowly to be playable, but I have not experienced any difficulty in using the editor. File | Save As... displays the usual Windows 3.x style file chooser and I was able to save a test .DGF file which the program subsequently reloaded. Unless there is some flaw in DOSBox's emulation of the filesystem, I don't know why you are unable to save levels.

When playtesting, the game under test runs in a new MDI window. The help file suggests pressing Ctrl+F4 to end the playtest (which closes the current MDI window) but closing the MDI window in other ways, such as double-clicking the icon to the left of the File menu, will be equally effective.

[image: "Daisy's Garden 2" screenshot, with the MDI menu icon highlighted]